# How can I define an interface for an array of destructured objects inside a map function?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, destructuring

So this is what I have so far. I tried numerous potential solutions but I keep receiving the same error below. Any leads or information would be very helpful.

```
interface RequestedOptions {
   name: string;
}

interface TicketOptions {
    serviceId: string;
    description: string;
    requestedAt: string;
    status: string;
    requester: RequestedOptions;
}

const tickets = transaction?.localTickets || [];

{tickets.map(
    ({ serviceId, description, createdAt, status, requester }: TicketOptions) => (
        <div className={styles.row} key={serviceId}>
        ...
```

This is the error that I get, all the time...

```
Argument of type '({ serviceId, description, createdAt, status, requester }: TicketOptions) => JSX.Element' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: { readonly serviceId: string | null; readonly description: string | null; readonly createdAt: string | null; readonly status: string | null; readonly requester: { readonly name: string | null; } | null; } | null, index: number, array: readonly ({ ...; } | null)[]) => Element'.
  Types of parameters '__0' and 'value' are incompatible.
    Type '{ readonly serviceId: string | null; readonly description: string | null; readonly createdAt: string | null; readonly status: string | null; readonly requester: { readonly name: string | null; } | null; } | null' is not assignable to type 'TicketOptions'.
      Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'TicketOptions'.ts(2345)
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that `transaction.localTickets` has type

```
interface TicketOptions {
    readonly serviceId: string | null;
    readonly description: string | null;
    readonly requestedAt: string | null;
    readonly status: string | null;
    readonly requester: RequestedOptions | null;
}
```

where `RequestedOptions` is

```
interface RequestedOptions {
   name: string | null;
}
```

So TS argues that your `TicketOptions` type and `transaction.localTickets` are incompatible. Just make `TicketOptions` and `RequestedOptions` as shown above and it should solve your issue.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. Unfortunately it still caused an error. Asked around the office and we had a utility assertion function that simply filters out nulls. That did that trick.